# Allow doubleClick on a textBox with IsEnabled = false

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox.

I want it to be in the Disabled state, so that I can drag it. Once I double click it I want it back to be Enabled.

I can use ReadOnly property for this purpose. But If I use ReadOnly, then I am unable to Drag the TextBox, instead I get selection.

My actual reason for doing this is I want to use TextBox as TreeViewItem and I would like to allow features like Rename and Rearrange using drag-drop.

If anybody can suggest something like custom control that I can create and override some method?

Comment: do you want to call some method or bind to the command?

Comment: I would like to handle MouseDoubleClick Event. I have got a solution. The event bubbling is my friend at this point. I listen for MouseDoubleClick on TreeViewItem instead of TextBox. Since TextBox is disabled, the event of TreeViewItem is fired.

Comment: that is what I was thinking, you may capture the events on parent container if feasible. if you need to handle on text box itself, then we may further dive into the same.

Comment: I think currently it works fine. But if you have any other solution then please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to wrap the TextBox inside Grid. And set IsHitTestVisible to false for textBox. This will avoid all mouse events for TextBox. Now hook all your drag events to grid and it will work.

```
 <Grid Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="5" Text="Some text"/>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Can I use other container types like StackPanel?

Comment: No, I checked it right now. It does not work. I cannot get the textBox in EditMode when I doubleClick it.

Comment: Currently my events are hooked up with TextBox and I make it to work using event Bubbling. After that I tried your solution and hooked all the events on StackPanel and now I cannot get TextBox in EditMode, when I double Click on it.

Comment: ((StackPanel)sender).Children[0] should give you the textBox.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I needed to make some changes in my code behind. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Vishal I doubt that you can use TAB to focus your TextBox and I think this behavior is not expected.

Comment: @KingKing If I stick with eventBubbling and IsEnabled=False then TAB does not make any unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Vishal ah yes, you can also set `Focusable` to false.